# Powershell Failed to get member output

Tags: regex, powershell, substring, select-string

I am trying use Regex to out the KB number out of `ProductName`.  All I get is an empty string.

```
gwmi -cl win32_reliabilityRecords -filter "sourcename = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" | 
select @{LABEL = 'KB#' ; EXPRESSION = {(Select-string -Pattern '{^"KB"/w*$}' -InputObject $_.ProductName)}}|fl
```

Comment: why u don't use get-hotfix command ?

Comment: get-Hotfix does not show fail installed updates.  I was going to take the failed update information then check to see a pattern of failures on the computers.  I am also going to use the fail install to check if the patch is waiting.  If it is waiting then I can assume that it is stuck and needs manual help.

Answer (score 2):

It might just be my limited exposure to and understanding of the .NET regex implementation but your pattern seems to make no sense at all, try with `\b(KB\d+)\b` instead:

```
Select @{n="KB";e={(Select-string -Pattern '\b(KB\d+)\b' -InputObject $_.ProductName).Matches[0].Captures[0]}}
```

`Select-String` returns a MatchInfo object, not the captured string itself. Note how the text that is actually matched and captured can be accessed through `.Matches.Captures`

If you are solely interested in the number, and not the entire string "KB??????", you could use a lookbehind to skip the `KB` part:

```
Select-String -Pattern '(?<=KB)(\d+)\b'
```

Comment: You are correct. The string does not start with KB like the ops regex syntax. Which is _one_ of the reasons he would have an empty string.

Comment: @Matt Updated answer, did I correctly catch your implied second reason it doesn't work? ;-)

Comment: Yes `MatchInfo` was the other important one. KB was not in quotes was another and using `\d`  over `\w`... think that was all. I am happy with your answer.